# Query an array in PyMongo

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to query an array using PyMongo and I am getting all the values instead of just the one matching **'A A'**

Format of Array:

```
"tags": [
        {
            "tag": {
                "name": "A A"
                    }
         }
         ]
```

Python Code:

```
import pymongo
from pprint import pprint


myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://00.00.00.0:27017")
mydb = myclient["dbName"]
mycol = mydb["thePage"]


for x in mycol.find({},{"_id": 0, "tags.tag.name":   "A A"}):
   pprint(x)
```

Result:

```
[{'tag': {'name': 'A A'}}, 
{'tag': {'name': 'B B'}},
{'tag': {'name': 'C C'}}]
```

Expected Result:

```
{'name': 'A A'}
```

I get the result I need using MongoDB:

```
db.dbName.where("tags.tag.name").eq("A A")
```

Comment: You need  a query filter.  `mycol.find({"tags.tag.name": "A A"})`

Comment: @styvane This is not working. It is returning all results not just the name but other variables

Comment: Use `$elemMatch` projection here... `db.collection.find({
  "tags.tag.name": "A A"
},
{
  "tags": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "tag.name": "A A"
    }
  }
})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am getting an `invalid syntax` near `$elemMatch` . My code:                                                                                                       
`myQuery = { "tags.tag.name": "A A" }, { "tags": { $elemMatch: { "tag.name": "A A" } } }`                                                                
 `for x in mycol.find({}, myQuery):`
  `pprint(x)`

Comment: Did the same ? https://mongoplayground.net/p/tqBuuNZVBNF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deconstruct the array first.
Try doing this:

```
mycol.aggregate([
    {'$unwind':'$tags'},
    {'$match': {
        'tags.tag.name':'A A',
    }},
    {'$project': {
        'tags.tag.name': 1, '_id': 0
    }},
])
```

Comment: Where does this go in my code? Sorry I am very new to Python and MongoDb

Comment: @newbierp  just substitute your `mycol.find` line with this.

Comment: I am getting a `self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 00.00.00.0:27017: timed out` error

Comment: You are having problem with your mongo service. Are you starting your mongo service from terminal?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I fixed that. But I have a new error now: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: path option to $unwind stage should be prefixed with a '$': tags`

Comment: Try copying my code again. i actually edited it a few minutes ago. you may not have the new one. Or you could just add a $ sign infront of tags. `{'$unwind':'$tags'}`.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed that too. But now that query is returning black `{}`

Comment: Thank you, thats what I did. Its not giving me any errors but its not giving me the result either. Its just giving `{}`

Comment: It was my bad. I had an extra space between the `A A`

Comment: SOrry for marking it late. I had a quick question I am trying to use a `LIKE` statement for the `'$match': {'tags.tag.name':'A A',}`. I tried to do `'$match': {'tags.tag.name':'/A A/',}` but I am getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually not an error, it is not returning anything

Comment: Isnt `{'tags.tag.name':'A A',}` an exact match  equivalent to `tags.tag.name ='A A'` in SQL. I was trying to do a Pymongo equivalent to `tags.tag.name LIKE '%A A%'`

Comment: Can you please help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52829141/query-tangled-array-in-pymongo