# Query tangled array in Pymongo

Tags: python, json, django, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to query a very tangled collection.

**The schema:**

```
{'tags': {'variables': [{'value': '3x9', 'var_name': 's'},
                     {'value': '12:00AM', 'var_name': 'x'},
                     {'value': 'goog', 'var_name': 'y'}]},
                     'url': 'https://www.google.com'}]
```

**The Query:**

```
res = mycol.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$tags"}
     ,{'$match': {'tags.tag.name':'A A', 'aR': 98765}}
     ,{'$project': {'url': 1, 'tags.vars': 1, '_id': 0}},])


res = list(res)
for x in res: 
    print(res)
```

**The Result:**

```
{'tags': {'variables': [{'value': '3x9', 'var_name': 's'},
                     {'value': '12:00AM', 'var_name': 'x'},
                     {'value': 'goog', 'var_name': 'y'}]},
                     'url': 'https://www.google.com'}]
```

**The Expected Result:**

```
[{'value': '3x9', 'var_name': 's'},
{'value': '12:00AM', 'var_name': 'x'},
{'value': 'goog', 'var_name': 'y'},
'url': 'https://www.google.com']
```

I will use it as a `HttpResponse` and use it as a `JSON` object.

Please Help!

Comment: Your schema is defined wrong. can you fix it with correct schema please?

Comment: @SaketKhandelwal, My schema is copied exactly from my terminal

Comment: Can you copy it from the mongodb db?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just say res['tags']['variables'] instead of res = list(res)?

Comment: `TypeError: 'CommandCursor' object is not subscriptable` This is my error